# css table of squares containing circles of different sizes

Tags: html, css

I want to make a drawing using css: 5 circles in a row going from biggest to smallest. I want the 5 circles to take up the width of the page even as a shrink the browser window.

```css
.main-circle-block {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.main-circle-block table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.main-circle-block td {
  border: 2px solid green;
  //border-radius: 50% (just to make them into circles)
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-circle-block inside-main">
  <table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to make a row a circles, with the first td tag containing the biggest circle, which would have a radius equal to half the width/height of the square and then radii 2, 3, 4 & 5 would get successively smaller.

I tried putting a div tags, giving them the size/border-radius I wanted inside the td tags but they just got squashed

Before this I also tried making a table of divs without the "padding-top: 20%" bit on the td tags, but then my circles turned into ellipses when I resized the browser.

I tried using a horizontal list making the li elements display: inline-block; but that didn't work (when i resized the browser, the circles popped around and didn't stay in a row)

1. Can what I want be done using the table tag?
2. Should I consider the horizontal list again?

I see some questions that are similar to mine but don't answer my question exactly.

Comment: It is not a good practice for using table in such application, use list or simply 5 `<span> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.square {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: black;
  height: calc(100vw * .20);
}
.circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.container div:nth-child(1) .circle {width: 90%; height: 90%;}
.container div:nth-child(2) .circle {width: 70%; height: 70%;}
.container div:nth-child(3) .circle {width: 50%; height: 50%;}
.container div:nth-child(4) .circle {width: 30%; height: 30%;}
.container div:nth-child(5) .circle {width: 10%; height: 10%;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <div class="square"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <div class="square"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <div class="square"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <div class="square"><div class="circle"></div></div>
</div>
```

**How It Works**

To keep the squares exactly the same height as their width we've used this line of code..

`height: calc(100vw * .20);`

What it says is to make the height of each `.square` 20% of the browser viewport width which (if your content area is 100% of viewport width) will match the width of each `.square` which are 20% of parent width because there are 5 of them.

`flex: 1;` in this case (5 divs) is pretty much saying set width to 20% and height to whatever 20% of width is in pixels. (because we've set height to that on the parent with calc earlier)

More about [calc](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) and [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on CSS Tricks.

If you're caring about older browsers (or IE anything) be sure to check [calc](https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) and [flex](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) compatibility on caniuse.com.

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/dehuv652/

Comment: this works beautifully. there are a few lines I haven't seen before so I'll study your code carefully. thanks a lot

Comment: @Jozurcrunch I've added some information to help you understand things a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thougths:
1) Yes, but no.. The way to achieve it is unsetting a lot of the predefined table's styles. At the end, it wouldnt be a table, so using this tag would be useless and semanticly the tag table do not offer too much to your idea, so, yes, you might force the css to get it done, but it might take you so much time that it'd be worthless.

2) Yes, but practically the same. I dont know what are you trying to get done, but if you desire i just having 5 circles in a row each smaller than the others, even the li tag would require a worthless effort. Maybe you could think about a "list of circles" but, till now, it has not much meaning.

Conclusion:

Use a more simple tag with less predefined styles. You can get this perfectly done, with even everything centered using the right display(flex suggested) and thinking the rights widths. This exercise will be a lot more worthy in my opinion

Comment: i don't know why I settled on the table or list tags. i guess I thought they would make it easier but they've become quite burdensome, at least insofar as this task is concerned. thanks for the advice